# emacsclient - discard unsaved changes on exit

Tags: emacsclient

I run `emacs --daemon` and `emacsclient`. When I `C-x C-c` from emacsclient, it will show the prompt

```
Save file /dir/filename.txt? (y, n, !, ., q, C-r, d or C-h)
```

for each file that has changes that haven't been saved.

If I enter `n`, emacsclient will exit, but then the next time I open emacsclient, it will ask me again if I want to save changes. Typically when I enter `n` I want to disacard the changes so that next time I run emacsclient, that file will be reverted to its state on disk.

How can I discard all unsaved changes when exiting emacsclient?

Current behavior:

- `emacsclient -a "" -t filename.txt`
- Make changes
- `C-x C-c`
- `Save file /dir/filename.txt? (y, n, !, ., q, C-r, d or C-h)`
- <kbd>n</kbd>
- `emacsclient -a "" -t filename.txt`
- `C-x C-c`
- `Save file /dir/filename.txt? (y, n, !, ., q, C-r, d or C-h)`
- <kbd>n</kbd>

Desired behavior:

- `emacsclient -a "" -t filename.txt`
- Make changes
- `C-x C-c`
- `Save file /dir/filename.txt? (y, n, !, ., q, C-r, d or C-h)`
- <kbd>n</kbd> (changes are discarded)
- `emacsclient -a "" -t filename.txt`
- `C-x C-c` (emacsclient exits)

Answer (score 1):

When done with a file opened through emacsclient, close it with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> (which runs `server-edit`), not <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>.

You can also define a function that closes all remaining server files:

```
(defun close-all-server-files ()
  "Close all server files"
  (interactive)
  (while (not(server-edit))))
```

Just bind it to a key and run it when needed.

Comment: my workflow will often involve opening many buffers (10+) over the course of a few hours. Then when I want to quit, I want to discard everything I haven't saved. So switching to each buffer and executing `C-x #` seems too tedious to me. Is there another way?

Comment: @mark: Check the update.

Comment: I added that function to my .emacs file, then opened a couple of files, edited them, and then ran `M-x close-all-server-files`. It produced the message `No server buffers remain to edit`. Then when I entered `C-x C-c` it prompted me about whether to save each file before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to simply delete your current emacsclient frame with `C-x 5 0`.  The daemon will continue to run and you won't be prompted about saving each buffer.